# How make surveys with many questions whose answers are very similar

Tags: 7, entities

I want build a survey with many different questions whose answers are of evaluation range kind (strongly disagree, disagree, neutral, agree and so on) or yes/not kind. I have to create n different fields (I suppose text list and boolean fields) or is there a better way?
I'm using Entity Form module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest using Survey [Builder module](https://www.drupal.org/project/survey_builder)

Key Features

1. Create survey forms with a drag and drop interface
2. Re-use questions across surveys (can be disabled)
3. Respond to surveys
4. Aggregate responses to surveys with Views

There some other nice modules too, such us [LimSurvey Sync](https://www.drupal.org/project/limesurvey_sync) or you can use [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) together with [webform builder](https://www.drupal.org/project/form_builder) which will save you a lot of time.